# Python and OpenCV - is there any way of making sure sliding at the trackbar of cv2.createTrackbar will give me an odd value?

Tags: python, opencv, callback

Let say I have this code:

```
cv2.createTrackbar('kernal', 'Window', 3, 21, callback)
```

For this time being, I just write another code underneath it to check weather the value I got from the correspond `cv2.getTrackbarPos` is odd or even, and if it is even, add one to it. Is there any other way like by using the `callback`? Because the irritating part with my way is that the slider will not really represent the value that I am getting (it will be one value lower if it is set up to an even number).

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, there is no certain way to get odd value. But you can use this piece of code to do optimizations:

```
val=cv2.getTrackbarPos('kernal', 'Window')
if val%2!=0:
    val+=1
```

Hope this helps.